# Image of $f(x)$ when $x$ is not in the domain of $f$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Joaquin Olivert's book *Estructuras de álgebra multilineal* (multilinear algebra sructures) states the following (p.38 thm. 5.9):

Let $f$ be a function (an special type of binary relation) and let $\mbox{def }f$ be the class the definition domain of $f$. Then:

$$
x\notin \mbox{def }f \Longrightarrow f(x) = \mathcal U
$$

and

$$
x\in\mbox{def } f \Longrightarrow f(x)\in \mathcal U .
$$

(here $\mathcal U$ denotes the class of all sets).

I have tried to prove it, but I have obtained something different (very different in fact). My attempt:

Let

$$
W=\{y : (x,y)\in f\}.
$$

By hypothesis $W=\emptyset$. Now, by definition, $f(x)$ is the second component of the class $W$, so:

$$
f(x)= \left(\bigcap\bigcap W\right) \cup \left(\left( \bigcup\bigcup W\right)\dashv \bigcup\bigcap W\right) ,
$$

where $A\dashv B$ denotes the complement of $B$ respect to $X$:

$$
A\dashv B= A\cap\{s:s\notin B\}.
$$

Computing:

$$
\bigcap\bigcap\emptyset = \bigcap \mathcal U = \emptyset.
$$

and

$$
\bigcup\bigcup \emptyset = \emptyset
$$

Since the complement involves the intersection with the emptyset, it turns out to be the emptyset again, so that

$$
f(x)=\emptyset.
$$

Any help?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT:

In the author's proof, he considers that

$$
f(x)=\bigcap W=\bigcap \emptyset = \mathcal U ,
$$

but I don't understand why $f(x)=\bigcap W $.

**Addendum.** The theorem actually states

$$
x\notin \mbox{def } f \Longleftrightarrow f(x)=\mathcal U,
$$

but it seems to be a mistake. Only $\Rightarrow$ is true.

**Addendum 2.** There was a mistake in my statement. First result said

$$
x\notin \mbox{def } f \Longrightarrow f(x) \in \mathcal U
$$

but the truth is $f(x)$ EQUAL TO $\mathcal U$.

Comment: I would certainly expect $x\in\operatorname{def}f\implies f(x)\in\mathcal U$ to hold, which seems hardly compatible with the iven claim.

Comment: The original claim does not look right at all. The $\Rightarrow$ direction _might_ be true depending on how _exactly_ you have defined the notation $f(x)$ -- but the $\Leftarrow$ direction is nonsense: Just because $f(x)$ is a set does _not_ imply that $f$ is not defined at $x$, with any sensible definitions.

Comment: This is the second part of the theorem. And his proof is the same. Now $W\neq\emptyset$ and by a previous theorem, $\bigcap W$ is a set (the theoreom is a corollary of subset axiom and the fact that if $y\in x$, then $\bigcap x\subset y$.

Comment: Also, I would expect $f(x)=\bigcap W$ to hold under normal circumstances (but also $f(x)=\bigcup W$)

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm agree with you. The statement is ''if and only if'', but the author only is worried by $\Rightarrow$. Thanks.

Comment: @HenningMakholm the notation is actually $f(x)=y$ to denote that $(x,y)\in f$.

Comment: Any other suggestions, please?

Comment: @Dog_69: Then how do you give meaning to the formula $f(x)\in\mathcal U$?

Comment: Because if $x\in\mbox{def } f$, by definition $x$ is a set. I'm don't know too much about that things, but I suppose $y=f(x) $ is a set, since $f$ is a function. So that it is true $f(x)\in \mathcal U$. What other sense could you do it to $f(x)$ to make the theorem coherence?

Comment: Is $f$ supposed to be a function? What is $\mathrm{def}(f)$? The domain of the function $f$? Is this theorem supposed to be true of all $f$, or just a specific $f$ you've forgotten to state?

Comment: @Hurkyl $f$ is a function and $\mbox{def } f$ its domain. I'll add it to my question. And the theorem is supposed to be true for all $f$.

Comment: Please some clarifications?

Comment: First comment: for the easy part, see Enderton page 41: if $\langle x,y \rangle \in f$, then $x,y \in \bigcup \bigcup f$. Thus: $x$ and $y$ are *sets*, and thus $x (\text { and } y) \in \mathcal U$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes. This is the result I get. But the author says $f(x)=\mathcal U$ not $\emptyset$. That is why my question.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes I know that property (is also proved in this books). The point is that if you defined $f(x)=y$, then $\bigcap W$ has no sense for me. It seems more logical my choose. You see my question know?

Comment: NO. If $x \notin \text { Dom } F$, we have that there is **no** sets $x, y$ such that $\langle x,y \rangle \in F$. If we write $F(x)=\emptyset$, this is $\langle x,\emptyset \rangle \in F$, and $\emptyset$ **is** a set... Contradiction.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: That is a great answer. You can consider write it as an answer and I'll mark it. Thanks a lot. Moreover, that comments also helps me with my another question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2618981/meaning-of-notation-fx-in-set-theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Comments*

We can see see H.Enderton, *Elements of Set Theory*, page 43: if $F$ is a function and $\langle x,y \rangle \in F$, there is a **unique** $y$ such that $\langle x,y \rangle \in F$.

We call it "the *value* of $F$ at $x$" and we can denote it with $F(x)$.

Because of this: $\{ y \mid \langle x,y \rangle \in F \} = \{ y \}$, and we know that $\bigcup \{ y \} = y$.

Conclusion: $F(x)=\bigcup \{ y \mid \langle x,y \rangle \in F \}$.

For the easy part, see Enderton page 41: if $\langle x,y \rangle \in F$, then $x,y \in \bigcup \bigcup F$. Thus: $x$ and $y$ are *sets*, and thus $x \text { (and } y ) \in \mathcal U$.

Regarding the second part, the author uses: $W = \{ y \mid \langle x,y \rangle \in F \}$.

But then, $W=\emptyset$ and $\bigcap W = \bigcap \emptyset$  (see Enderton, page 25) is the class $\text V$ of all sets (i.e. $\mathcal U$).

But the issue is: writing $F(x) = \mathcal U$ makes little sense, because again the "meaning" of $F(x)$ is "the **unique** $y$ such that $\langle x,y \rangle \in F$" and obviously $\langle x, \mathcal U \rangle \notin F$, otherwise (see above): $x, \mathcal U \in \bigcup \bigcup F$, that implies that $\mathcal U$ is a set.