# Meaning of notation $f(x)$ in set theory

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

In my book, a function $f$ is defined as a binary relation such that if $(x,y),(x,z)\in f$ then $y=z$. Moreover, as it is usual, author denotes $(x,y)\in f$ by

$$
y=f(x) .
\tag{1}
$$

So, from this notation, I understand $f(x)$ as the second component of the ordered pair $(x,y)\in f$, i.e $(x,f(x))$. Nevertheless, below, the author says that $f(x)=\bigcap\{y:(x,y)\in f\}$. But I think this notation is different from (1), since

$$
\bigcap\{y:(x,y)\in f\} = \{z: \forall y:(x,y)\in f \Longrightarrow z\in y\} ,
$$

I mean, $\bigcap\{y:(x,y)\in f\}$ is a set of elements of the class $y$, not such a $y$.

And, moreover, some other authors, as Herbert Enderton, define also $f(x)$ as the class

$$
f(x)=\bigcup\{y:(x,y)\in f\} .
$$

How can be all these notations/definitions compatibles?

Comment: They're compatible as long as $x \in \operatorname{dom} f$

Comment: They also assume that the $y$s are sets

Comment: Is $\text{dom}$ short for *domain*? I have never seen that notation before.

Comment: @user477343: Yes. That notation is standard all across mathematics.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thank you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $A$ is a singleton, $\{a\}$ then $\bigcap A=\bigcup A=a$. Since $f$ is a function, the set $\{y : (x,y)\in f\}$ is a singleton, for a fixed $x$, so the result follows.

The key point to remember is that *everything* is a set, including $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I'm not a set! I'm a free number!

Comment: You are number $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Comment: I don't see where you get the fact that he is $6$? Any hints?

Comment: @WeijunZhou: Then you didn't get the joke... :)

Comment: @WeijunZhou [Hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prisoner)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Very nice your answer. I didn't think that possibility. I'm fell quite stupid...  What happen  if we don't consider sets? Because in my book exists such a possibility. In fact, you would be very kind if you could look at my questions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2614892/image-of-fx-when-x-is-not-in-the-domain-of-f  Here I consider the posibility that $x\notin \mbox{dom } f$, as jkbrg said before. Thanks

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for enlightening me.

Comment: @Dog_69: By Herbert you mean Enderton? Let me say that since you require $(x,y)\in f$, then if $x$ is not in the domain of $f$ you get $\bigcap\varnothing$, which is by [most] definition[s] the class of all sets.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Herbert Enderton. Yes, but now if you change $\bigcap$ by $\bigcap$ you get $\bigcup \emptyset =\emptyset$. And that is another doubt for me

Comment: @Dog_69: I doubt that Enderton, at any given point of time, ever considered a function that *returns* a non-set object, let alone a proper class. And since in set theory, you don't care about $f(x)$ when $x$ is not part of the domain of $f$, might as well have it return the empty set by default. You can judiciously apply what someone wrote in a book about multilinear algebra to what is written in a book about elementary set theory. Yes, there are common elements to both, but you need to view the broader context, too.

Comment: @Dog_69 - see Enderton, *Elements of Set Theory*, page 23: $\bigcup A$ is defined as $\{ x \mid x \text { belongs to some member of } A \}$. Thus, if $A$ is $\emptyset$ it has no member. So, there are no $x$ that "belongs to some member of it"; i.e. $\bigcup \emptyset$ is empty.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: No, I wanted to say that Herbert Enderton define $F(x)$ as the union, not the intersection. But, as you said, he writes ''We hereby resolve to use this notation [$F(x)$] _only_ when $F$ is a function and $x\in\mbox{dom } F$.''.

Comment: And see page 43: if $F$ is a function and $\langle x,y \rangle \in F$, there is a **unique** $y$ such that $\langle x,y \rangle \in F$: we call it "the *value* of $F$ at $x$" : $F(x)$. Because of this: $\{ y \mid  \langle x,y \rangle \in F \} = \{ y \}$ and: $\bigcup \{ y \}=y$. Conclusion: $F(x)= \bigcup \{ y \mid  \langle x,y \rangle \in F \}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Even it is a book of linear algebra, it has a first part dedicated to Axiomatic set theory. In addition, the author considers many generalitie. I mean, generically, he works with classes, not only with sets.

Comment: @Dog_69: Working with classes still requires a proper set up for the context and all that. I don't feel that this is the time or place to get into all of that, but again, you need to remember that set theory is generally about *sets* and classes play a second violin to sets. And therefore basic set theory is often taught in the settings of ZF(C) and variants thereof, and not NBG or KM which are class-enabled set theories. And even then, mostly $F(x)$ is only reserved for the case where $x$ is in the domain of the function, because otherwise it is meaningless or uninteresting.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: So do you think I can define $f(x)= \bigcup\{y:(x,y)\in f\}$ instead of $\bigcap$ because when $x\in\mbox{dom }f$ it does not matter? The fact than then $f(x)=\emptyset$ instead of $\mathcal U$ when $x\notin\mbox{dom } f$ is not important?

Comment: @Dog_69: I don't know what the book wants to do with functions later on, so I can't quite tell you what's important and what is not. You could argue that a function which returns a proper class is a way of saying "this is undefined" whereas returning the empty set might be a valid output, so that could be an easy way to identify the domain of a function. Yeah, that really depends on the book.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you so much for you patience and your answers. I'm going to mark your answer as a valid. It, together with your comments I think is a very successful and complete answer. Thank also Mauro for his interest on my questions. Finally just one comment about the book: Its purpose is to develop (multi)linear-algebra theory. But it does it with an incredible level of rigorousity and abstraction, really improper of those books. In my opinion, it requires a certain level on maths to be able to understand well many of its results and explanations.

Comment: @Dog_69: You're welcome. In any case, many mathematical topics require some preliminary "mathematical maturity". Even those that can be developed naively, can—and should—at some point be developed rigorously. The trick is to match the reader with the book.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Mauro ALLEGRANZA has answered my related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2614892/image-of-fx-when-x-is-not-in-the-domain-of-f. Yoy can look at it if you want. I think it also applies to our conversation here.